# How to combine multiple lists into 1 list without using zip()

Tags: python, list

I want to combine multiple lists into 1 list without using `zip()` since `zip()` will convert `expected_list` to a list of tuples. I want `expected_result` is a list of lists.

```
list1 = [ "a" 
          "b" 
          "c" ]
list2 = [ "e" 
          "f"
          "g" ]

expected_list = [ [ "a", "e" ]
                  [ "b" ,"f" ]  
                  [ "c" ,"g" ] ]
```

any solution for this ?

Comment: thanks Chirs for edding my post. How could you put zip() into the grey background ?

Comment: have you tried using list comprehensions in conjunction with zip?

Comment: Why not use `zip`, but then convert the `tuple`s to `list`s?  `expected_list = [list(t) for t in zip(list1, list2)]`

Comment: Note that `list1` and `list2` here each have one member: a three character string. You're missing commas so Python is concatenating adjacent string literals.

Comment: @mht, inline code can be marked with backticks (`\``), e.g. `...without using \`zip()\` since...`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[[i, j] for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Or as [ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65255201/how-to-combine-multiple-lists-into-1-list-without-using-zip#comment115365561_65255259) wrote below:

```
list(map(lambda *x: list(x), a, b)).
```

Comment: The question specifically says `without` using zip. Your answer uses zip.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, but this was an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). OP _thought_ the solution was not to use `zip()`, but what they really wanted was a list of lists. This gives that result.

Comment: FWIW - without zip: `list(map(lambda *x: list(x), a, b))`.